# Error importing Zelle's graphics.py package

Tags: python, zelle-graphics

I am working though Zelle's Python book (Python 2.7.5, Canopy Express, Windows 7).  For Chapter 5 you need to install his graphics package, graphics.py.  I downloaded the current version, put it in the `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages` folder and made sure the file has the '.py' extension, but when I type >>import graphics I get the following error in both Canopy and IDLE:

```
ImportError    
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-e6fd1288a7fc> in <module> ()
----> 1 import graphics

ImportError: No module named graphics
```

To the best of my knowledge I've followed the instructions and hints on the website and here in StackOverflow, but I'm flummoxed.  Any suggestions?  I like the Zelle book but I'm not sure how much use it will be from this point on without the graphics package - from just skimming it seems like the majority of the examples and exercises use it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It took a while, but I got it working.  Enthought Canopy uses its own (virtual) environments, so you need to put Zelle's graphics package there, not in the system library.  I had success by placing graphics in Enthought's top level directory, which you can determine in the interpreter:

```
 >> import site
 >> site.getpackages()[0]
```

I copied the graphics package there, without the .py extension, fired up Canopy and I was off and running.  Thanks to everyone who has posted, in various places, tips on importing - eventually it made sense!  By the way,

```
 >> site.getpackages()
```

will give you all site package directories, but I only needed the first.